# Sending an email to about 10K users (NOT SPAM!)

Tags: email, newsletters

After an update to my website I need to send a mail to all my users (about 10K).

I got the data email,user,new_pass in a plain CSV file.

Do you know any good service that can import the mail template and user data and send the mails?

Thanks

Comment: What website does this belong to? I am inclined to believe it should be on SF, but I am not too sure

Comment: When sending 10.000 emails, there's a risk that your ISP will block your account during or after sending those messages! So, call your ISP to notify them that you're going to send a large amount of emails to subscribed members! Some ISPs already block users s soon as when only 50 emails are sent out within a short timespan!

Comment: see also http://serverfault.com/questions/68357/whats-the-best-way-to-send-bulk-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a website that has that many users, I guess you have full control over a server.

I highly recommend you install [PHPlist](http://www.phplist.com/). It is overkill on small sites, but for a site with as many users as yours, it has many nice features such as auto pruning of dead addresses (and on a 10k list, you need it!).

[Full features](http://www.phplist.com/details)

Answer (score 1):

Preventing your server from being listed on one of the many spam blacklists (you can check if you are already listed [here](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso)) and managing/configuring the underlying mail server (postfix etc) is a considerable amount of hassle. If you are considering sending more than one mail to your subscribers, I would recommend outsourcing this to a 3rd party such as [mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/pricing/) (pay as you go pricing would be preferable). There is also a free version for up to 500 subscribers.

If you simply require a single mail shot, then make sure:

- Your server has MX and reverse DNS records
- You have SPF DNS records (many servers reject
  mail without a valid SPF, GMail for
  example)
- Your mailserver's HELO
  response matches your hostname
- Your mailserver is not an open relay

Answer (score 0):

I second the PHPList recommendation.
It allows you to send mails in batches and to throttle the send process so that you do not exceed your IPS's hourly limit.
It is a little bit of work to set up and configure.

I do think that ConstantContact, MailChimp etc charge exorbitant fees for their services, and they get away with it because of the barriers that a normal guy sending out emails faces. For larger numbers of subscribers, this quickly turns into real money.

If this really is a one-time deal, you probably don't want to set up PHPList. It took me a few days and several test mailings to get it working. In this case, I recommend http://www.easycontact.com/packages.html (have not actually used them) because their pricing is on a per-campaign basis as opposed to a subscriber-basis.

Answer (score 0):

We use PHPlist and it can be a bit of work to get going. Not even so much for the technical details of installing PHPlist and your rDNS settings, [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/), [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/), etc., but getting your ip whitelisted, working with the different webmail providers to pass your e-mail on. I think it comes down to how valuable your time is. It took me about a day to get the software technically running and another week or part time work to get the majority of the e-mail providers accepting our e-mail.

If you have the time to invest to get PHPlist running, it's worth it, but if not, I'll put in another plug for [ConstantContact](http://www.constantcontact.com) or [iContact](http://www.icontact.com/).  I've not used either, but a few friends I know do, rather than administer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

PHPList will work but if you don't want to use existing infrastructure, which I'd recommend to keep any possibilities of being flagged as a spam server, you can use a commercial mailing service such as mailjet.com

I personally try to separate mass mailing from my production infrastructure.